# Saving a servlet response when it is a pdf generated with oracle's report server

Tags: servlets, oraclereports

My application is deployed on Oracle's OAS (ADF environment). My application is a simple form with a submit button. When it's clicked I send a request the Oracle's report server (to the rwservlet). My request look something like this:

```
http://<server>:<port>/reports/rwservlet?report=<report_name>&userid=<userid>/<password>@<connect_string>&desformat=pdf&destype=cache
```

This generates a PDF report and returns to the user's browser. I'd like to get that PDF report and save it to my local server as well (so I have 2 servers: the OAS server and the Reports Server - and I called the report on the Reports server and return to the client. I just want to intercept the process and save the report on the OAS server).

To send the request, I used a servlet on my OAS server. I want to somehow get the PDF from my response object (that's my plan). I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't intercept/copy client's request. You've to request it programmatically with another HTTP request.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://<server>:<port>/reports/rwservlet?report=<report_name>&userid=<userid>/<password>@<connect_string>&desformat=pdf&destype=cache").openStream();
// ...
```

Just write it to an arbitrary `OutputStream` the usual Java IO way. For example, a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Hey BalusC, I used this idea, but implemented it a bit differently...I sent a post request then write the response to a local file. Works great. The resource that I'm requesting is password protected, so had to get around that. Thank you though, your reply got me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. You can find an example of sending POST requests by `URLConnection` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Comment: wow...yea, exactly what I ended up doing. But seems like a lot more stuff here. Thanks for the link